# How do I find the index of an item in a vector?

Tags: clojure

Any ideas what `????` should be? Is there a built in? 
What would be the best way to accomplish this task?

```
(def v ["one" "two" "three" "two"])

(defn find-thing [ thing vectr ]
  (????))

(find-thing "two" v) ; ? maybe 1, maybe '(1,3), actually probably a lazy-seq
```

Comment: Brian's is clearly the answer to this question, but below, cgrand and Alex Stoddard conspire to answer the question that I should have asked.

Comment: Nothing stops you from asking the correct question in a separate question :)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Built-in:

```
user> (def v ["one" "two" "three" "two"])
#'user/v
user> (.indexOf v "two")
1
user> (.indexOf v "foo")
-1
```

If you want a lazy seq of the indices for all matches:

```
user> (map-indexed vector v)
([0 "one"] [1 "two"] [2 "three"] [3 "two"])
user> (filter #(= "two" (second %)) *1)
([1 "two"] [3 "two"])
user> (map first *1)
(1 3)
user> (map first 
           (filter #(= (second %) "two")
                   (map-indexed vector v)))
(1 3)
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks Brian, my doc-searcher didn't find indexOf, presumably because it's Java. I shall have to work on it.

Comment: @John: Yes. The dot before indexOf indicates Java interop. It calls the method 'indexOf' in java.lang.String. java.lang gets imported by default. For more examples see http://clojure.org/java_interop

Comment: It's the vector's `indexOf` method that that gets called, not String's: `#<Method public int clojure.lang.APersistentVector.indexOf(java.lang.Object)>`

Comment: If you're doing a map-indexed and a filter, you might also look at keep-indexed.

Answer (score 50):

Stuart Halloway has given a really nice answer in this post http://www.mail-archive.com/clojure@googlegroups.com/msg34159.html.

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.seq :only (positions)])
(def v ["one" "two" "three" "two"])
(positions #{"two"} v) ; -> (1 3)
```

If you wish to grab the first value just use `first` on the result.

```
(first (positions #{"two"} v)) ; -> 1
```

EDIT: Because `clojure.contrib.seq` has vanished I updated my answer with an example of a simple implementation:

```
(defn positions
  [pred coll]
  (keep-indexed (fn [idx x]
                  (when (pred x)
                    idx))
                coll))
```

Comment: Very nice! This is the sort of answer I was expecting.

Comment: Not that it affects the merit of this answer, but seq-utils has been changed just clojure.contrib.seq now.

Comment: where to get `clojure.contib.seq` in clojure 1.6? No library in list: http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go

Comment: @d9k, "If a clojure.contrib namespace is listed here but has no migration details, that means no one has volunteered to maintain that namespace." I added an example implementation for `positions`.

Answer (score 29):

```
(defn find-thing [needle haystack]
  (keep-indexed #(when (= %2 needle) %1) haystack))
```

But I'd like to warn you against fiddling with indices: most often than not it's going to produce less idiomatic, awkward Clojure.

Comment: Oh nice 'when'! I agree about indices generally, but I have a csv file, and the names of the fields are in the header, and I want to get the field "field" from each row, so what I'm doing is looking "field" up in the header, and then nthing the rows. I can think of strange things to do with interleave, but is there a nice way that doesn't use explicit indices that's readable?

Comment: When I have that use-case - csv headers - I have just built a map to do the lookup (assuming unique column headers). The map _is_ then my function to do index lookup. (let [header-index (zipmap header-vector (iterate inc 0))] ...)

Comment: Wow. You answered the question I should have asked!

Comment: Well, I would have proposed something very semblable to Alex's solution. (-> "colname" header-index row) and you have your value.

Answer (score 14):

As of Clojure 1.4 clojure.contrib.seq (and thus the `positions` function) is not available as it's missing a maintainer:
http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go

The source for `clojure.contrib.seq/positions` and it's dependency `clojure.contrib.seq/indexed` is:

```
(defn indexed
  "Returns a lazy sequence of [index, item] pairs, where items come
  from 's' and indexes count up from zero.

  (indexed '(a b c d))  =>  ([0 a] [1 b] [2 c] [3 d])"
  [s]
  (map vector (iterate inc 0) s))

(defn positions
  "Returns a lazy sequence containing the positions at which pred
   is true for items in coll."
  [pred coll]
  (for [[idx elt] (indexed coll) :when (pred elt)] idx))

(positions #{2} [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]) => (1 5)
```

Available here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.seq/positions

Comment: Thanks for posting this version. Since 1.2 you can also replace (iterate inc 0) with simply (range).

Answer (score 7):

I was attempting to answer my own question, but Brian beat me to it with a better answer!

```
(defn indices-of [f coll]
  (keep-indexed #(if (f %2) %1 nil) coll))

(defn first-index-of [f coll]
  (first (indices-of f coll)))

(defn find-thing [value coll]
  (first-index-of #(= % value) coll))

(find-thing "two" ["one" "two" "three" "two"]) ; 1
(find-thing "two" '("one" "two" "three")) ; 1

;; these answers are a bit silly
(find-thing "two" #{"one" "two" "three"}) ; 1
(find-thing "two" {"one" "two" "two" "three"}) ; nil
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my contribution, using a `loop`ing structure and returning `nil` on failure.

I try to avoid loops when I can, but it seems fitting for this problem.

```
(defn index-of [xs x]
  (loop [a (first xs)
         r (rest xs)
         i 0]
    (cond
      (= a x)    i
      (empty? r) nil
      :else      (recur (first r) (rest r) (inc i)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to find indexes several times or rather I chose to since it was easier than figuring out another way of approaching the problem. Along the way I discovered that my Clojure lists didn't have the .indexOf(Object object, int start) method. I dealt with the problem like so:

```
(defn index-of
"Returns the index of item. If start is given indexes prior to
 start are skipped."
([coll item] (.indexOf coll item))
([coll item start]
  (let [unadjusted-index (.indexOf (drop start coll) item)]
    (if (= -1 unadjusted-index)
  unadjusted-index
  (+ unadjusted-index start)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to loop the whole collection if we need the first index. The `some` function will short circuit after the first match.

```clj
(defn index-of [x coll]
  (let [idx? (fn [i a] (when (= x a) i))]
  (first (keep-indexed idx? coll))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with reduce-kv

```
(defn find-index [pred vec]
  (reduce-kv
    (fn [_ k v]
      (if (pred v)
        (reduced k)))
    nil
    vec))
```