# Find index of an element matching a predicate in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

With Clojure, how do I find the first index with a positive value in this vector `[-1 0 3 7 9]`?

I know you can get the first result of something rather elegantly with `first` and `filter`:

```
(first (filter pos? [-1 0 99 100 101]))
```

This code returns the value `99`.  The answer I want is the index which is `2`.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830900/how-do-i-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-vector

Comment: My question is totally different. I've edited my title to reflect this.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using [`keep-indexed`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/keep-indexed) you can get a sequence of indices for which a predicate is satisfied:

```
(defn indices [pred coll]
   (keep-indexed #(when (pred %2) %1) coll))
```

With this simple function you'll solve your problem with the expression

```
user=> (first (indices pos? [-1 0 99 100 101]))
2
```

Note that, due to the lazyness of `keep-indexed` (and `indices`), the entire sequence need not be realized so no extraneous calculations are performed.

Comment: This works great. (As I dug into it, I noticed that `keep-indexed` includes **non-nil** (which includes `false`) results. I don't know the rationale for this.)

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn first-pos [x] 
  (loop [arr x n 0]
     (if (pos? (first arr))
     n
     (recur (next arr) (inc n)))))
```

This is a good example of using functional programming's powerful tail recursion.

Comment: It fails with a `NullPointerException` if there are no positive elements in the list; also OP was asking for the match of an arbitrary predicate, not only `pos?`

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn pred-idx [pred [idx hist] cur]
  (if (pred cur)
    [(inc idx) (conj hist idx)]
    [(inc idx) hist]))

(defn idx-filter [pred col]
  (second (reduce (partial pred-idx pred) [0 []] col)))

(first (idx-filter pos? [-1 0 99 100 101]))
2
```

Not sure if this is better, but it works. I think it forces evaluation of the entire sequence though, and if you need all indices that would be better. The correct thing to do is probably turn it into a lazy sequence somehow, but I'm done for the evening.

Comment: I want something that can handle my example.  Find the index of the first positive value in a collection.

Comment: I had this stuck on the brain, so kept trying. Not an ideal solution though.

Answer (score 1):

```
(first (filter #(not (nil? %)) (map #(when (pos? %1) %2) [-1 1 0 99 100 101] (range))))
```

Map can take one or more collections and return one list,put condition on map,and filter nil.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but I prefer:

```
(defn index-of-pred
  [pred coll]
  (ffirst (filter (comp pred second) (map-indexed list coll))))

;; example usage
(index-of-pred pos? [-1 -2 -5 0 3 4 1 -100])
;=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(defn first-index
  ([pred coll] (first-index coll pred 0))
  ([pred coll idx]
    (cond (= coll '()) -1
          (pred (first coll)) idx
          :else (recur pred (rest coll) (inc idx)))))
```

And use it like this:

```
(defn is-pos? [x]
  (> x 0))

(first-index is-pos? [-1 0 3 7 9])
```

It returns the zero-based index of the first element that satisfies the predicate (`is-pos?` in the example), or -1 if no element matches the predicate.

Comment: This function will only return -1 if passed `nil` explicitly, because `(rest x)` is never nil for any `x`. You should be calling `seq` on the collection before testing it for nil. Also, `[pred coll]` would be a friendlier argument order than `[coll pred]` - cf. `map` and `filter`, for example.

Comment: this works (with amalloy's suggestions), but the version using keep-indexed is much simpler.

Comment: There, I've edited it according to @amalloy's comment. Coming from a Scheme background, it's weird that nil != '() in Clojure

Answer (score 0):

```clj
(defn first-idx
  ([pred]
   (fn [coll] (first-idx pred coll)))
  ([pred coll]
   (reduce-kv
     (fn [_ idx val] (when (pred val) (reduced idx)))
     nil
     coll)))

(first-idx nil? [:a :b nil])       ;; ~> 2
((first-idx nil?) [:a :b :c nil])  ;; ~> 3
(first-idx nil? nil)               ;; ~> nil
(first-idx nil? [:a :b :c])        ;; ~> nil
```