# :use fails in lein project

Tags: clojure, namespaces, leiningen

When I try to use

```
   (ns eight-puzzle.core
      (:use [clojure.contrib.seq :only (positions)]))
```

I get this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/seq__init.class or        clojure/contrib/seq.clj on classpath: 
          RT.java:443 clojure.lang.RT.load
          RT.java:411 clojure.lang.RT.load
        core.clj:5530 clojure.core/load[fn]
        core.clj:5529 clojure.core/load
      RestFn.java:408 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
        core.clj:5336 clojure.core/load-one
        core.clj:5375 clojure.core/load-lib[fn]
        core.clj:5374 clojure.core/load-lib
      RestFn.java:142 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
         core.clj:619 clojure.core/apply
        core.clj:5413 clojure.core/load-libs
      RestFn.java:137 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
         core.clj:621 clojure.core/apply
        core.clj:5507 clojure.core/use
      RestFn.java:408 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
     NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 eight-puzzle.core/eval8699[fn]
     NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 eight-puzzle.core/eval8699
```

And this problem happens when ever I try to import anything in. Did I do something wrong when setting up clojure?

Comment: Is this a lein project with a project.clj file or a single file run with the clojure.jar?

Comment: yes it is a lein project. does that make a difference

Comment: Does your project.clj file contain the `[org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]` dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External dependencies, for projects managed by Leiningen, should be specified in the `project.clj` file, under the `:dependencies` key.

```
(defproject project1 "0.0.1"
  :description "Something"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [clj-time "0.6.0"]])
```

**Note:** The entries in `:dependencies` can originate from either maven ([maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/)) or [Clojars](https://clojars.org).

It also looks like you are using `clojure.contrib`. This library has been deprecated and you should [upgrade](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib), if you can. If you are only using `clojure.contrib.seq/positions`, take a look at this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532584/17048). You can also reimplement it with just clojure.core functions:

```
(defn positions [pred coll]
  (for [[idx elt]
        (map-indexed vector coll)
        :when (pred elt)]
    idx))
```