# Returning positions of an element Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming, lisp, iteration

I am trying to find a solution to a problem i am facing at the moment, i have tried and tried to get this working but to no avail.  I am trying to scan a list containing data and then returning the position of the data if found.

For example if i ran this:

```
(ind 'p '(l m n o p o p))
```

Then i would get a return value of....

```
==>  4 6
```

As it has found the data in those positions.

I have come close i think to what i want with this solution before, but i cannot get it to run.  Can anyone help me figure out whats up with my function?? As far as i can see it should work, but i cant figure out why it isnt?

```
(defn ind
([choice list emptylist x]
(let [x (count list)])
(if (= (x) 0)
  nil)
(if (= (first list) item)
  (ind item (rest list) (cons x emptylist) (dec x))
  (ind item (rest list) emptylist (dec x))
  )
 )
)
```

What i have tried to do is loop through the list until it hits a value and add it to the empty list and once it has looped through return the empty list.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830900/how-do-i-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-vector

Answer (score 5):

I found that there is a built-in function called [`keep-indexed`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep-indexed) in Clojure.

So you can simply do this:

```
(keep-indexed (fn [idx elm] (if (= 'p elm) idx)) '(l m n o p o p))
; return (4 6)
```

Comment: Suggest you frame this as the required function: `(defn ind [x coll] (keep-indexed (fn [idx elm] (if (= x elm) idx)) coll))`

Comment: Wow, I have never seen that function before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which I think is a bit simpler:

```
(defn find-index 
  "Returns a seq of the indexes of the supplied collection."
  [values target]
  (let [indexes           (range (count values))
        val-idx-tuples    (map vector values indexes) 
        found-tuples      (filter #(= target (first %)) val-idx-tuples)
        found-indexes     (vec (map second found-tuples)) ]
    found-indexes))

(println (find-index '(l m n o p o p) 'p ))

;=> [4 6]
```

Comment: You can do without `indexes`. Just say `(let [val-idx-tuples    (map vector values (range)) ... ] ...)`. The `map` terminates when any of the collections runs out. You can get a similar effect using `map-indexed` instead of `map`. I'd also leave out the final `vec`. Then the whole thing is lazy, so the client can decide how and when to realise it.

Answer (score 0):

Though I prefer [@chanal's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33535845/1562315), you can write the function you want as follows:

```
(defn ind [x coll]
  (loop [ans [], coll coll, n 0]
    (if-let [[y & ys] (seq coll)]
      (recur (if (= x y) (conj ans n) ans) ys (inc n))
      ans)))

(ind 'p '(l m n o p o p))
;[4 6]
```

This uses several idioms to make it concise:

- `if-let` comprises `if` inside `let`.
- The destructuring form `[y & ys]` comprises calls to `first` and `rest`.
- Pushing the `if` form down into the `recur` avoids repetition.